# Shared variable & threading.Lock

Tags: python, multithreading, synchronization, locking

In Java, unless you use atomic operations or some other thread sync mechanism, you might have stalled values for a shared variable in a thread.

Given the GIL, in CPython. I see the value of a Lock inc cases where:
Multiple steps are taken before assigning a value, even in the confusing `a += 1` idiom. To prevent race condition.

But in a case like `a = 1`, without a Lock. is it possible to have threads A and B reading different values of a after some thread updated it?

Another way of asking this question would be, does Lock ensures shared value propagation and lack of Lock does not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue isn't the `a = 1`.  If the only thing you're doing throughout your code is setting `a` to various values, then you don't need locks.

But if at the same time you're setting `a = 1`, you have somewhere else in your code that's doing `a = a + 1`, then you need to lock both of them.  You're locking `a = 1` so that if someone else increments `a`, it will happen either completely before or completely after you've set `a`.

So in almost all cases, unless you really know what you're doing, a lock is the simplest solution.